# Comparing two DataFrames by one column with a return of three different outputs with Panadas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am beginner in Python and coding. I need help comparing two dataframes of different lengths and with different column labels except one. The column that is the same between the two datasets is the column I want to compare the dataframe by. My data looks like this:

```
    df:  'fruits'  'trees'      'sports'    'countries'  

          bananas   mongolia     basketball    Spain
          grapes    Oak          rugby         Thailand
          oranges   Osage Orange baseball      Egypt
          apples    Maple        golf          Chile

    df2: 'cars'  'flowers'     'countries'    'vegetables'

          Audi    Rose          Spain           Carrots
          BMW     Tulip         Nigeria         Celery
          Honda   Dandelion     Egypt           Onion
```

I would to compare these two dataframes based on the column 'countries'and create three separate outputs each in their own dataframe. I have been using Pandas and have used pd.concat to combine df1 and df2 into one. I would also like to keep the rows of the rest of the dataframe even though they don't match.

Here are my desired outputs:

Output# 1: Values in df NOT in df2:

```
    d3:  'fruits'  'trees'      'sports'    'countries'  

          grapes    Oak            rugby         Thailand
          apples    Maple          golf          Chile
```

Output# 2: Values in df2 NOT in df

```
        df4: 'cars'  'flowers'   'countries'    'vegetables'

              BMW     Tulip       Nigeria         Celery
```

Output# 3: Values in both df AND df2 (with the columns from the different dataframes combined.)

```
df5: 'fruits'  'trees' 'sports'  'cars' 'flowers' 'countries' 'vegetables'  

  bananas   mongolia  basketball   Audi    Rose      Spain    Carrots 
Oranges  Osage Orange baseball    Honda   Dandelion  Egypt    Onion
```

Hope this all makes sense. I have tried so many different things (isin, DataFrame.diff and .difference, df-df2, numpy arrays, etc.) I have looked all over and I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

***Setup Reference***

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt1 = """fruits,trees,sports,countries
bananas,mongolia,basketball,Spain
grapes,Oak,rugby,Thailand
oranges,Osage,Orange baseball,Egypt
apples,Maple,golf,Chile"""

txt2 = """cars,flowers,countries,vegetables
Audi,Rose,Spain,Carrots
BMW,Tulip,Nigeria,Celery
Honda,Dandelion,Egypt,Onion"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt1))

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt2))
```

---

#### Solution

```
def outer_parts(df1, df2):
    df3 = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
    return {n: g.drop('_merge', 1) for n, g in df3.groupby('_merge')}


dfs = outer_parts(df, df2)
```

---

#### Demonstration

```
dfs['both']
```

[image]

```
dfs['left_only']
```

[image]

```
dfs['right_only']
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. Although, if I wanted to keep all 8 columns together for each output, what would be the best way to do that? Then have the values that don't match be 'NaN'.  Also the 'Both' output doesn't seem to be working for me. I seem to get blank values under the column countries that are in both df1 and df2. I guess its possible that my two dataframes don't have any matching countries and the ones that do match are blanks in my dataframe. All the values seem to either be 'left_only' or 'right_only' under the '_merged' column. There aren't any 'both' values in that column. Thanks!

Comment: @J.L. I updated answer.  there was a typo.  Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Is there a difference between df and df1?

Comment: Is there a difference between df and df1? If so, what is the difference?  I'm not getting the desired results. @piRSquared Is there a way to compare by a specific column? I compare the column 'countries' from df1 to the column 'countries' in df2 and find which countries are only in df1, which ones are only in df2, and which countries that are located in both df1 and df2 all while retaining all other columns and rows.

Comment: `df` and `df2` were the names of the dataframes you provided.  `df1` and `df2` **within** the `outer_parts` function are their own things.  In this example, I pass `df` and `df2` to the function `outer_parts` and that gets manipulated inside the function as `df1` and `df2`.  That's a long way of saying... yes, `df` is the same thing as `df1`, sort of, only while inside the function.  Hopefully I didn't confuse things too much.

Comment: No worries, that does make sense now. Thank you. @piRSquared I do have one more question, what are n: and g standing for in the script? I just want to make sure I understand how python was able to retrieve the outputs I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: I am still having trouble. Its not comparing the column 'countries' in df to the column 'countries in df2. When I do this the result is pretty much still these two dfs. The only items I am getting for 'both

Comment: the only items I am getting for commonalities between df and df2 in 'both' are 'NaN' blanks in the  column 'countries'. I know there are common entries in df and df2 along the 'countries' column so something isn't right. @piRSquared Basically the result of right only is df2 and left only is df1. There aren't any changes.